# Is it possible to add custom parameters to Firebase Analytics automatically tracked screen_view events?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

Is there a way to add custom parameters to Firebase Analytics "screen_view" events?

These events are automatically tracked and the documentation only references setScreenName.

The only alternative I can think of is manually tracking screen_views in addition to the automatic tracking, but looking to see if there are better options.

Comment: What is the use case for custom params for screen view events? Each screen name is already attached to each event, so can you just use a custom events instead?

Comment: It looks to me like you can only track the screen name. https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews I guess if you do it manually you can add some additional information.

Comment: I tried to dispatch it as a normal event, but with name "screen_view". It was ignored by analytics. I tested it using firebase DebugView.

Comment: Still here 4 years later.

Comment: Still here 6 years later

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName);
bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, "MainActivity");
bundle.putString("custom_parameter", "parameter_value");
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW, bundle);
```

Answer (score 0):

They recommend to send the event again in `viewDidAppear`, find [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews#manually_track_screens) here

> You can manually log screen_view events whether or not automatic tracking is enabled. You can log these events in the onAppear or viewDidAppear methods for Apple platforms and onResume for Android. When screen_class is not set, Analytics sets a default value based on the UIViewController or Activity that is in focus when the call is made.

```
Analytics.logEvent(AnalyticsEventScreenView,
                   parameters: [AnalyticsParameterScreenName: screenName,
                                AnalyticsParameterScreenClass: screenClass])
```